# document.addEventListener 'copy' not working on IE

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener

I work on angular 4 and I want to copy some text on click of a button. For this I am using an `addEventListener`. The problem is the text is getting copied in Chrome but not in IE. I am not getting any error in IE console, below is my code

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e: ClipboardEvent) {
      const strCopy = 'some text to be copied';
      e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', strCopy);
      e.preventDefault();
    }.bind(this));
```

Please guide me how to resolve the issue. Thanks

(I am using IE 11)

Comment: [Check the compatibility for that event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy#Browser_compatibility), it isn't supported in IE.

Comment: Microsoft has stopped new developments in IE & moved to Edge browser now, only security updates are now released for IE. Doesn't seems IE will get that feature

Comment: So, whats the alternative to this? Any ideas?